I'm being routed to Staging Ground for my 2nd question
I understand Staging Ground is for users who are asking their first question. However, it's not my first question, and it's still taking me to the Staging Ground interface.
Also, when I posted my first question a few weeks back, it let me post it directly without entering Staging Ground.
Is this the intended behaviour?


As mentioned in this answer, to qualify as an asker in the Staging Ground you need to have fewer than two successful questions. Currently you have only one question which can be considered successful (Since it is answered). Considering this, you qualify for being an asker in the Staging Ground.

when I posted my first question few weeks back it let me post it directly without staging ground.

Not all of the qualified askers are currently routed to the Staging Ground only part of them so that the Staging Ground doesn't have more questions than the reviewer capacity.
